# Sending GET multiple times

Tags: django

I want to send to server post filtered by category:

```
/?category=IT
```

But then when I load this page I want to sent by GET method next parameter for instance:

```
/?category=IT&nav=next
```

but how to do this? How to send once again category without clicking on it?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
def post_list(request):

categories = Category.objects.order_by('name')
if request.method == 'GET':
    if 'category' in request.GET.keys():
        posts = Post.objects.order_by('-created').\
            filter(category=Category.objects.filter(name=request.GET['category']).first())
    else:
        posts = Post.objects.order_by('-created')
    if 'nav' in request.GET.keys():
        if request.GET['nav'] == 'older':
            pass
        elif request.GET['nav'] == 'newer':
            pass
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'newest': posts[0], 'posts': posts[1:],
                                                   'categories': categories})
```

Comment: Could you describe your general purpose?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You just can use `/?category=IT&nav=next` - you can add `nav=next` params for that page.